# Vapor pass date parameter

Tags: swift, date, vapor

In my Vapor 3 app, I have an `Event` model, which has the properties `startDate: Date` and `endDate: Date`.
Now, I'm wondering how to pass those date values in a POST request. In Postman, I tried the following in `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
startDate -> 2019-03-14
```

This returns the error below:

> Could not convert to `Double`: str(\"2019-03-14\")

Apparently, `Date` turns into `Double`.
So, instead, what value do I need to pass?

---

#### Note

I know, that, in Postman, I can insert `{{$timestamp}}`, but 1) this doesn't answer my question when using the API outside Postman and 2) this doesn't allow me to enter a date other than *now*.

Comment: It looks like `Content` decoder for `x-www-form-urlencoded` expects a `TimeInterval` aka `Double` for dates. So you could use unix-timestamp for passing date to the server. But I've just tried to post a 0 as date and Vapor decoded it as 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 thought it definitely should be 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000. So it looks like a bug somewhere, but I'm unable to find it in Vapor's source code yet....

Comment: Hm 2001 is even weirded. How about a JSON body? @imike

Comment: I've just checked it and answered below cause code snippets aren't supported in comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the `Date` object is returned in the following format when queried:

```
2021-12-31T14:29:00Z
```

So this is what I tried to pass and that worked! No need for any custom decoding.

Answer (score 4):

So the issue here is that by default, a `Date` instance is decoded using the time interval since Jan 1, 2001. The [URL form decoder](https://github.com/vapor/url-encoded-form/blob/master/Sources/URLEncodedForm/Codable/URLEncodedFormDecoder.swift) that Vapor uses doesn't support different date strategies like the `JSONDecoder` does at the moment, so you'll have to do the decoding a different way. Here are a couple of ideas I could come up with:

- Just send the timestamp in the request. For testing different dates in Postman, you can set an environment variable in the pre-request script and access that in the request body.
- Manually implement the `Event.init(from:)` and `.encode(to:)` methods. Just to make sure you don't break the Fluent coding, you will probably have to add some extra logic, but it should work. Here's an example:

  ```
  final class Event: Model {
      static let formDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
          let formatter = DateFormatter()
          formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
          formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
          formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
          formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
          return formatter
      }()

      var startDate: Date
      var endDate: Date

      init(from decoder: Decoder)throws {
          let container = try decoder.container(keyedby: CodingKeys.self)

          if let start = try? container.decode(String.self, keyedBy: .startDate), let date = Event.formDateFormatter.string(from: start) {
              self.startDate = date
          } else {
              self.startDate = try container.decode(Date.self, keyedBy: .startDate)   
          }

          if let end = try? container.decode(String.self, keyedBy: .endDate), let date = Event.formDateFormatter.string(from: end) {
              self.endDate = date
          } else {
              self.endDate = try container.decode(Date.self, keyedBy: .endDate)   
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll go with the date formatter and string solution, I guess.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Apparently the way I created the date formatter isn't thread safe. You will want to create the formatter in a NIO `ThreadSpecificVariable`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about `x-www-form-urlencoded` cause I tested it and if I send a date as `0` it decodes it as `2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` thought it definitely should be `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`.

But with JSON payload you have a flexibility cause you could provide a `JSONDecoder` configured as needed for you.

```swift
struct Payload: Content {
    var date: Date
}
```

#### If you'd like to send dates as UNIX-timestamp

```swift
router.post("check") { req throws -> Future<String> in
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970 // choose it for unix-timestamp
    return try req.content.decode(json: Payload.self, using: decoder).map { p in
        return String(describing: p.date)
    }
}
```

#### If you'd like to send dates in your own format

```swift
router.post("check") { req throws -> Future<String> in
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter) // custom date formatter
    return try req.content.decode(json: Payload.self, using: decoder).map { p in
        return String(describing: p.date)
    }
}
```

So for unix-timestamp you should send seconds from 1970 and e.g. `0` will be decoded to `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`.

And for custom format described above you should send dates like `2018-01-01 00:00:00` to decode it as `2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`

#### UPD: you could write an extension to decode it beautifully

```swift
extension ContentContainer where M: Request {
    func decodeJson<D>(_ payload: D.Type) throws -> Future<D> where D: Decodable {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
        return try decode(json: payload, using: decoder)
    }
}
```

so then you'll be able to decode your payload like this

```swift
router.post("check") { (req) throws -> Future<String> in
    return try req.content.decodeJson(Payload.self).map { p in
        return String(describing: p.date)
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess I'm going to go with the date formatter solution. Seems a little friendlier on the eyes...  Thanks!

Comment: Also you could use an extension, please take a look at the updated answer :)